# On url hash change success - in Angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, state, directive

app I'm wokring on is using `states` and `ui-sref` for routing (also there is Kendo but I don't know atm does it affect routing). I have 5 tabs on `html` (same state - just `#tab-x` changes from `#tab-1` to `#tab-5`). I have directive bound to every of tabs and in directive, I use `$location` service to determine current url. Problem is: when I

```js
console.log($location)
```

it show correct "#tab-x" but when I use $location.$$url to do some handlings, it shows previous tab value. Is there any "location change success" event I can use here? I tried :

```js
$scope.$on("locationChangeSuccess", function (event, next, current) {
});
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: If you take a look at my question carefully, you can see "same state" so this event does not fire.

Answer (score 0):

The event is there, but is prefixed with $ sign:

```
$scope.$on("$locationChangeSuccess", function (event, next, current) {
    console.log($location.hash());
});
```

You can use `$location.hash()` to get the value.

Working plunker here: https://plnkr.co/edit/KEJft8iwbxN3VfBhikIU?p=preview

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#event-$locationChangeSuccess

This is angularjs event. You could also use `$stateChangeSuccess` event of ui-router, as @Satpal noted in comments, but that event will probably not be called as the state does not change really (you do not have defined states with including the hash, right?).

Also you should not use `$$` prefixed properties, those are meant to be private.

Comment: I just forgot to write $ sign, for some reason it doesn't fire. Nor stateChangeSuccess fires (as I said state remains same just value after hash changes).

Comment: Well `$locationChangeSuccess` should be firing when url hash changes (have this tested somewhere in one project). `$stateChangeSuccess` is probably not firing as the state really did not change...

Comment: Are you sure you do not have some typo there?

Comment: I created plunker with this, it is working fine, so if there is a problem, it lies somewhere else in your code...